# Perl Change Content Type Of Response

Tags: perl, soap, content-type

I am calling a SOAP web service as client.
Following is content-type value of response

```
Content-Type: text/xml
```

I requested customer to add UTF-8 to response as follow:

```
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
```

But customer says that it can be from client side. Is this possible? Can I determine content type of server as client?

Comment: What library you are using for SOAP servcie?

Comment: I am using SOAP::Lite

Comment: As far as i understand, customer means that you should send proper headers, like "text/xml; charset=utf-8" and it's default behavior, unless you've specified " $SOAP::Constants::DO_NOT_USE_CHARSET = 1;". You may clarify what your customer mean and use debug/trace to check if everything is right.

Comment: I am client. Customer is server. Web service is called by me and customer returns data to me. But data returned by customer as response includes illegal characters which gives Parser error at my code. When I called at debug mode, I saw that content-type of response is without UTF-8. I requested customer to add UTF-8 to content-type. But they said they can not do it. I told them that, because response is sent by them it should be done by them. Because I am only calling their web service without any parameter and they return data to me.

Comment: As a result, my header is "text/xml; charset=utf-8" which is default but header of response is "text/xml;". As a client, can I add "charset=utf-8" to value of content-type of response? Is this possible? I think I can determine only my header not server's but customer claims opposite

Comment: You can't modify headers sent to you by remote server. You may try to ask them to use specific charset with Accetp-Charset for example. But again, it's better to ask them what they mean by "you may do it yourself"

Comment: Also, can you show us the exact error message and some of the illegal characters? I'd also support trying "$SOAP::Constants::DO_NOT_USE_CHARSET = 1;" as an experiment.

Comment: Does your request has Accept-Charset: utf-8 ?

Comment: @AlexandrEvstigneev I asked them to set content-type to "UTF-8" before sending response but they say that web service has been written with PL-SQL and there is no option to set it with code. It can be set at database level only and they say that their database character set is "UTF-8". But when I call web service at debug mode and with SOAP-UI, I don't see UTF-8 at content-type value

Comment: @HughBarnard   Following is error message:

not well-formed (invalid token) at line 10, column 27, byte 371 at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.5/i386-linux-thread-multi/XML/Parser.pm line 187

Illegal characters are lile geometric shapes: triangle, square. But these are for only Turkish characters

I tried $SOAP::Constants::DO_NOT_USE_CHARSET = 1 but did not work

Comment: @MarcoMunari how do I set it? I am using same code for other customers and I don't have problems at characters

Comment: @MarcoMunari I asked them to set content-type to "UTF-8" before sending response but they say that web service has been written with PL-SQL and there is no option to set it with code. They say that It can be set at database level only and they say that their database character set is "UTF-8". But when I call web service at debug mode with Perl and with SOAP-UI, I don't see UTF-8 at content-type value of response. Even at SOAP-UI which is independent from language. But at SOAP-UI, Raw data is correct, XML data is incorrect.

Comment: @AlexandrEvstigneev with the comment  "you may do it yourself" they mean that it should be done by me with the API I used (SOAP::Lite). They say that I can determine content-type of their response.

Comment: All you can do is to send header, like Accept-Encoding or send charset for your request. You should use debugging mode to see if they are set.

Comment: This: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2508641?tstart=0 on the Oracle website looks like a related problem and the 'seeds' of the solution at the server end. As an architectural matter, it should be fixed at that end, if at all possible. Sorry to be vague!

Answer (score 0):

PS: I noticed that the cited RFC2376 is obsolete by RFC3023 (conservative enough) and then RFC7303 that I'm omitting to evaluate now in involved current use and content, so the relevance of the following might not be that definitive, I'm feeling to delete it.

You have everything formal in [RFC2376 XML Media Types: Section 3.1 text/xml Registration](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2376#section-3.1)
See also *Section 6 Examples* of that RFC, particularly [Section 6.4 text/xml with Omitted Charset](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2376#section-6.8)

The server side (your customer) is `STRONGLY RECOMMENDED` to use `charset` parameter that they are not currently using.
And if `charter` is omitted `XML processors MUST use the default charset value of "us-ascii"`

You are right asking the customer to specify charset, the "MUST" in the RFC is a strong requirement that limits also your adaptability from client side when they are not sending us-ascii.